# Overlapping random divs

Tags: javascript, random

I'm making a simple game (whack a mole), the game works like this:
Every time you press the start button, it will place 10 divs into the DOM.
The divs will be placed randomly into the DOM.

My problem is that they overlap each other and sometimes they're place outside of their container.

I'd like to know how can i place them randomly inside the container without overlapping each other, i prefer not to use a grid to place them, i want them to be randomly distributed across the container.

here's the main function:

```
function randomPos(size){
var result = new Array();
var height = (document.getElementById('field').clientHeight);
var width = document.getElementById('field').clientWidth;
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    var posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
    var posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
    if (result.length == 0){
        obj.x = posX;
        obj.y = posY;
        result.push(obj);
    }
    else{
        var flag = true;
        for (var j = 0; j < i && flag; j++){
            if (result[j].y == posY && result[j].x == posX){
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        if(flag){
            obj.x = posX;
            obj.y = posY ;
            result.push(obj);
        }
        else{
            i--;
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
```

here's a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s5cv2n8y/)

Comment: You would want to determine the full area of screen space taken up by a div. If a div is 100x100, then you'd want to essentially block off that area of the screen as an option when generating new divs.

Comment: can you elaborate with details about how to do it practically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the function that I modified -

```
function randomPos(size){
    var result = new Array();
    var height = (document.getElementById('field').clientHeight);
    var width = document.getElementById('field').clientWidth;

    var generatePos = function(){
        // generates the random x and y position, taking into account the size of the object
        var posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - 140) + 40);
        var posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - 100));
        return {x: posX, y: posY}
    }

    var checkOverlap = function(x, y){
        var no_overlap = true
        // loops through existing objects and makes sure the newly generated one doesn't overlap
        for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++){
            var yDiff = Math.abs(result[j].y - y)
            var xDiff = Math.abs(result[j].x - x)
            if (yDiff < 100 && xDiff < 100){
                no_overlap = false;
            }
        }
        return no_overlap
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var obj = {};
        var pos = generatePos()
        if (result.length == 0){
            obj.x = pos.x;
            obj.y = pos.y;
            result.push(obj);
        }
        else{
            var no_overlap = checkOverlap(pos.x, pos.y) 
            if(no_overlap){
                obj.x = pos.x;
                obj.y = pos.y ;
                result.push(obj);
            }
            else{
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s5cv2n8y/6/

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing, is it possible to make the height to start from 40px instead of 0? I want to keep the first 40px for a bar with game points and timer.

Comment: Yep.  With `Math.random` the general formula is `Math.random() * (max - min) + min`.  So use `Math.random() * (height - 140) + 40`.  I'll update that also